# How to set alignment in main body view?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to align an `Image` in the first body view to the top but can not find a way to do this. I want set an alignment to `.top` like you would do in a `ZStack`, like this:

```
ZStack(alignment: .top) {
    Image("imagename")
    Text("Test")
}
```

In this code the text, in front of the image, would be at the top. How would I do the same but the image is the body view and the text is the image.

Comment: Just to understand what you want, think in terms of X, Y, and Z - a common coding scenario. X is horizontal, Y is vertical, and Z? Probably best described as *layers*. With this in mind are you wanting to position your image **on top** (or above) of the the other elements in the body, or on **the**top of the other elements? If it's the former, we probably need to know what else is in the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another use for `GeometryReader` ([read more here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/geometryreader))!

```swift
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                Image(systemName: "person")
                }.frame(width: geometry.size.width, alignment: .top)
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I wanted. I’m currently watching the WWDC tutorials of SwiftUI but will have to read more about these features.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use Spacer.

```swift
var body: some View {

  VStack(alignment: .center) {
      Image(systemName: "person")
      Spacer()   
  }

}
```

I actually wrote a [blog post](https://benmcmahen.com/using-spacer-in-swiftui/) about how you can use Spacer to create fairly complex layouts.

Comment: This also works! It's great to know all the different options but I think Apple should implement a simpler way to do this.